# Java FX image upload from file

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

i was trying create a image icon on label text field using  file chooser but the current code works for java and not java fx
if anyone know to fix my code it will be very helpful

```
package EmploymentPayroll;

import java.awt.Image;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author Shafeen
 */
public class AddEmployeeController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label img;
    private ImageIcon format = null;
    String filename = null;
    byte[] person_image = null;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }

  @FXML
    private void UploadImageActionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();

        filename = f.getAbsolutePath();
        *error*  ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(filename).getImage().getScaledInstance(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));

        *error* img.setIcon(imageIcon);       


         try {
            File image = new File(filename);
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream (image);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos= new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            for(int readNum; (readNum=fis.read(buf))!=-1; ){
                bos.write(buf,0,readNum);
            }
            person_image=bos.toByteArray();
        }

        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
        }

    }
```

this is the java fx form where when i click on picture it should load the file and save as BLOB type

[image]

error one

[image]

error two

[image]

thanks for help

Comment: JFileChooser and JOptionPane is also Swing and not JavaFX. Stick to JavaFX if you want your program to be written in JavaFX.

Comment: Use `javafx.stage.FileChooser` and `javafx.scene.control.Alert` instead of the equivalent Swing APIs. And since this is JavaFX you should be using `javafx.scene.image.Image` / `javafx.scene.image.ImageView` instead of `java.awt.Image` / `javax.swing.ImageIcon`. As a general rule, avoid mixing UI toolkits unless you absolutely _have_ to. Remove everything related to AWT/Swing, use the available JavaFX APIs instead, and try again. If you're still having a problem, please provide a [mre].

Comment: And note you would use `label.setGraphic(imageView)` to add an image graphic to a `javafx.scene.control.Label`. I recommend reading some tutorials on JavaFX; check out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/index.html

Comment: java naming conventions, please!

Comment: i got the code working thank you for the efforts

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is looking to upload images using java fx and save in database in blob format then you can refer this code
thank you

```
@FXML
    private void UploadImageActionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

        //Set extension filter
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterJPG
                = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("JPG files (*.JPG)", "*.JPG");
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterjpg
                = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("jpg files (*.jpg)", "*.jpg");
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterPNG
                = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("PNG files (*.PNG)", "*.PNG");
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilterpng
                = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("png files (*.png)", "*.png");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters()
                .addAll(extFilterJPG, extFilterjpg, extFilterPNG, extFilterpng);
        //Show open file dialog
        File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

        try {
            BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(file);
            WritableImage image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImage, null);
            img.setImage(image);
            img.setFitWidth(200);
            img.setFitHeight(200);
            img.scaleXProperty();
            img.scaleYProperty();
            img.setSmooth(true);
            img.setCache(true);
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];

            for (int readNum; (readNum = fin.read(buf)) != -1;) {
                bos.write(buf, 0, readNum);
            }
            person_image = bos.toByteArray();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger("ss");
        }
    }
```

```
byte[] person_image = null;

 @FXML
    private void handleaddemployee(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        try {
                String empID = "nill";
                if (!txtempID.getText().equals("")) {
                    empID = txtempID.getText();
                }

                Employee e = new Employee(
                        empID,
                        person_image 
                );
                dbemployee.addEmployee(e);

            } else {
                 System.out.println("not working");
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
           System.out.println("error");

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
         System.out.println("number error");

        }

    }
```